# How to concatenate values from MySQL SELECT

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have

```
SELECT name 
FROM table
```

which gives me something like

```
foo
bar
baz
```

and I need to join all the values, to make it into one string like

```
foo bar baz
```

so I guess it would be something like

```
foreach row in (select ...) 
   var += row
```

but I have absolutely no idea how to write it in MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(bar) FROM TABLE GROUP BY foo;
```

Comment: That will return NULL if any of the values are null. You might want to CONCAT each one and run ISNULL(foo, 'NULL') on each value to ensure you get results.

Comment: Or simply add a WHERE clause to exclude nulls.

Comment: Agreed, it depends on the requirements.