# How do I concatenate string values from a lookup table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: upload, tag and upload_tag. Upload holds details of a file upload, tag holds tag names and upload_tag is a lookup table which matches upload ids to tag ids i.e:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| upload                                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|id         |name                                        |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|1          |file_1.jpg                                  |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|2          |file_2.doc                                  |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+

+--------------------------------------------------------+
|tag                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|id         |name                                        |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|1          |a_tag                                       |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|2          |b_tag                                       |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|3          |c_tag                                       |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+

+--------------------------------------------------------+
|upload_tag                                              |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|upload_id  |tag_id                                      |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|1          |1                                           |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|1          |2                                           |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|2          |3                                           |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|2          |2                                           |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

I need to pull uploads from the database with the string of tags, but all in one row so the result would look like:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|filename      |tags                                 |
+--------------+-------------------------------------+
|file_1.jpg    |a_tag; b_tag                         |
+--------------+-------------------------------------+
|file_2.doc    |c_tag; b_tag                         |
+--------------+-------------------------------------+
```

At the moment I'm thinking that the best way to do this would be to create a MySQL function which takes an upload id and returns the formatted string of tags. Am I correct here, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate values from MySQL SELECT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091746/how-to-concatenate-values-from-mysql-select)

Comment: @Ken : this is bit similar BUT not duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `LEFT JOIN` clause and the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.

```
SELECT          u.name AS filename,
                GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR '; ') AS tags
    FROM        upload u
    LEFT JOIN   upload_tags ut
        ON      u.id = ut.upload_id
    LEFT JOIN   tag t
        ON      t.id = ut.tag_id
    GROUP BY    u.id;
```

`GROUP_CONCAT` is an aggregate function, meaning it works on multiple rows (organized as groups) as opposed to `CONCAT` which works on multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
select 
upload.name as filename
GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name SEPARATOR '; ') as tags
from 
upload_tag ut 
inner join upload  on (ut.upload_id = upload.id)
inner join tags on (ut.tag_id = tags.id) 
group by ut.upload_id
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN` with upload_tag as the base table will only fetch those filenames that have tags. It's reasonable to say that you want to use filenames even if they don't have any associated tags.